# How to remove the title bar without changing the theme appcelerator?

Tags: android, themes, appcelerator-mobile, titlebar

I am developing an app for android using Accelerator. I want to hide the TitleBar from some windows in my app.

I tried different themes, it removes the title bar but also changes the colors of all the labels and textfields and the colors of the window, I just want to remove the titlebar that's all with no other modification.

Here is the code that I've tried. I added it to my window.

```
theme: "Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar
```

So basically what this code does is hide the title bar but modifies all the colors of all objects (label, textfield, pickers), it makes them white,

How ever I tried to do

```
Color:'black'
```

to each one of them but nothing it doesn't respond, still white.

Comment: show your styles.xml file

Comment: where could i find it ?

Comment: res > values > styles

Comment: i don't have one  i have , styles_apptheme.xml and some other files i guess they're irrelevent

Comment: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); before setcontentview method does not hide title bar?

Comment: is this function exists in titanium Appcelerator ?

Answer (score 0):

if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
     getSupportActionBar().hide();

use this code in your respected activity.

Comment: getSupportActionBar()  is not defined , my project is in Appcelerator titanium not java android